# How to pass decryption certificate password as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Using SQL Server 2012 v11.0.2100.60, I am trying to create a stored procedure that opens a symmetric key with decryption by certificate with password.

If I put the hard-coded password in the stored procedure it works fine, but I would like to be able to pass the certificate password as a parameter to the stored procedure (so that the plaintext pw doesn't live anywhere on the server).

Here's what I've tried.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testSproc]
    @pw VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY key_name  
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE cert_name WITH PASSWORD = '''+@pw+''';

    SELECT ....
```

When I execute I get the following:

> Msg 15466, Level 16, State 9, Procedure testSproc, Line 9
>   An error occurred during decryption.

This is what it looks like when I execute:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[testSproc]
        @GL = N'98787notTheRealPW45668456318'
        -- I've tried both N'98787notTheRealPW45668456318' and just '98787notTheRealPW45668456318'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Am I passing the parameter incorrectly? Or setting the variable in the stored procedure incorrectly? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Put the OPEN KEY command into it's own variable and pass in the pw there. Then just execute.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testSproc]
    @pw NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @SQL = 'OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY key_name DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE cert_name WITH PASSWORD = '''+@pw+'''';

    EXEC (@SQL)
    SELECT ....
```